# Right click detection on a block (No item on hand) Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I modify this code to detect a right click when right-clicking a specific block only, without any item in a player hand? This is not like others, for I am not using an Item or I am not right-clicking any object. Just a specific one like a torch, to act like a button. I can use scorebords with this though.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Activated] action 1 {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{}]}
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Activated] action 0 {Equipment:[{id:"minecraft:carpet"},{},{­},{},{}]}
/execute @e[name=Activated,score_action_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /setblock XYZ-Coordinates redstone_block
/execute @e[name=Activated,score_action=0] ~ ~ ~ /setblock Same XYZ-Coordinates air
```

Comment: I believe this is a limitation that minecraft has. There is no way to really detect a right click without having mobs surround a players and doing lots of funky stuff for a system that halfway works. It would be nice if they added a stat that states "times right clicked", but without that or a scoreboard value we can't do it.

Comment: I can have a scoreboard. Or are you saying that won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a villager with no trades and a `stat.talkedToVillager` objective. This is because a villager without trades doesn't show the trade interface at all.

Summon an invisible ArmorStand with an invisible, silent Villager as it's passenger, like this:

```
/summon ArmorStand <x> <y> <z> {
  Invisible:1b,
  Marker:1b,
  NoGravity:1b,
  Passengers:[{
    id:Villager,
    Silent:1b,
    NoAI:1b,
    Invulnerable:1b,
    Career:1,
    CareerLevel:6,
    Offers:{Recipes:[]},
    ActiveEffects:[{
      Id:14b,
      Amplifier:0b,
      ShowParticles:0b,
      Duration:2147483647
    }]
  }]
}
```

Copy-paste version of the command:

```
/summon ArmorStand <x> <y> <z> {Invisible:1b,Marker:1b,NoGravity:1b,Passengers:[{id:Villager,Silent:1b,NoAI:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Career:1,CareerLevel:6,Offers:{Recipes:[]},ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:0b,ShowParticles:0b,Duration:2147483647}]}]}
```

The armor stand serves purely as a way to hold the villager in place. Play around with `<x> <y> <z>` until you find a good position for the villager. I suggest temporarily removing the villager's invisibility effect for "alignment" by replacing `2147483647` with `0`.

Now, create your objective

```
/scoreboard objectives add torchLever stat.talkedToVillager
```

Use a repeat/chain command block line to run the following commands:

```
/execute @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R,score_torchLever_min=1] ~ ~ ~ <your command>
/scoreboard players set @a torchLever 0
```

Replace `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `R` with appropriate values. This is to prevent triggering your torch lever when interacting with *any* villagers.

Comment: I have not used anything this large and complicated yet, but reading this should work. I will be able to try it later today, and I will get back to you if this works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it right. Could you show me an example? With the command set to change the time to day?

Comment: @Akidus I have created a small testworld showcasing the commands: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/7X7AaxbZm2YzJYI

Comment: I have one more question. I can't figure out how to make it be used again to change it to day and night. But I'm using it with blocks. So, when you hit the block, it will glow. Hit it again, it will go off. How?